# Unable to upload a file in one click when using two input file type in same form

Tags: javascript

I want to use two input file types to upload the logo and image in the file upload script. But when I try to use `input[type=file]` for a second time I need to double click to attachment image to upload. I want to upload the image in two places in one click to load the file upload image. Anyone help me to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var readURL = function (input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    $(".file-upload").on('change', function () {
        readURL(this);
    });

    $(".upload-button").on('click', function () {
        $(".file-upload").click();
    });
});
```

```css
.profile-pic {
  display: block;
}

.file-upload {
  display: none;
}

.file-upldr {
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 112px;
  height: 110px;
  transition: all .3s;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/favico-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
}

.file-upldr .change-pic img.favico-pictur {
  width: 38px;
}

.file-upldr img.profile-pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.choose-image input.file-upload {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.change-pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.change-pic .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.change-pic p {
  margin: 5px 0 -5px;
}

.file-upldr:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.file-upldr:hover .change-pic, .file-upldr:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-form">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="choose-image">
        <div class="file-upldr vdo-upldr favico-upldr upload-button">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="">
          <div class="change-pic">
            <img class="favico-pictur" src="images/favicon-small.png">
            <p>Upload</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-form">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="choose-image">
        <div class="file-upldr vdo-upldr favico-upldr upload-button">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="">
          <div class="change-pic">
            <img class="favico-pictur" src="images/favicon-small.png">
            <p>Upload</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are some things that you need to fix:

1. in your function `readURL` pass the jquery object `$(this)` to can read the corresponding element class `.profile-pic` with the `siblings` method.
2. To read the input this with jquery you need to read the element with `[0]` to get the corresponding element.
3. You need to specify the element that is the brother of the `input[type='file']` with the method `siblings`.
4. Define the name of each input element (this is important if you
   don't want to have problems in the future)

Check the code snippet and see if that is what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var readURL = function (input) {
        if (input[0].files && input[0].files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                input.siblings('.upload-button').children('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input[0].files[0]);
        }
    }


    $(".file-upload").on('change', function (e) {
    
        readURL($(this));
    });

    $(".upload-button").on('click', function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
        $(".file-upload").click();
    });
});
```

```css
.profile-pic {
  display: block;
}

.file-upload {
  display: none;
}

.file-upldr {
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 112px;
  height: 110px;
  transition: all .3s;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/favico-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
}

.file-upldr .change-pic img.favico-pictur {
  width: 38px;
}

.file-upldr img.profile-pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.choose-image input.file-upload {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.change-pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.change-pic .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.change-pic p {
  margin: 5px 0 -5px;
}

.file-upldr:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.file-upldr:hover .change-pic, .file-upldr:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-form">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="choose-image">
        <div class="file-upldr vdo-upldr favico-upldr upload-button">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="">
          <div class="change-pic">
            <img class="favico-pictur" src="images/favicon-small.png">
            <p>Upload</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input name="image1" class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-form">
      <label>Image</label>
      <div class="choose-image">
        <div class="file-upldr vdo-upldr favico-upldr upload-button">
          <img class="profile-pic" src="">
          <div class="change-pic">
            <img class="favico-pictur" src="images/favicon-small.png">
            <p>Upload</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input name="image2" class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```